# Convert JavaScript to CSS media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm running into page performace issues and I believe this block is causing the biggest slowdown:

```
  // Section menu on mouseover, hide menu on mouseout
  // Can be more concise using .toggleClass?
  $('section').live('mouseenter', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1278) {
      $(this).find('menu').removeClass('hidden')
      $(this).find('div.section-wrapper').addClass('active')
    }
  }).live('mouseleave', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1278) {
      $(this).find('menu').addClass('hidden')
      $(this).find('div.section-wrapper').removeClass('active')
    }
  })
```

For the record, I'm aware `.live()` is deprecated and will eventually switch to `.on()`. I'm under the impression this only runs when mouseenter and mouseleave occur, but with it, the page performance is poor - especially for mobile.

I'm trying to convert this to a css media query so it runs faster but the following block of SASS isn't cutting it:

```
@media(min-width: 1279px) {
  section:hover {
    menu.hidden {
      display:block;
    }
    section .section-wrapper {
      border: 1px #ddd solid;
      padding: 14px;
    }
  }
}
```

`.active` just adds a border and changes the padding to accommodate. `section:hover` appears to do nothing. I added `section {background-color: #E1C2E2;}` within the media query for troubleshooting and it's working fine. Ideas? Could it be nested SASS with media queries causing the slowdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple case of css hierarchy and not covering my bases with undoing twitter bootstrap's `.hidden` class. This does the trick:

```
@media(min-width: 1279px) {
  section:hover {
    menu.hidden {
      display: block;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .section-wrapper {
      border: 1px #ddd solid;
      padding: 14px;
    }
  }
}
```

As for performance, it was this block that was causing a much bigger slow down:

```
  $(window).bind('load resize orientationchange', function(){
    $('#main_menu').trigger('testfit')
    if ($(window).width() < 1278) {
      $('section').find('menu').removeClass('hidden')
      $('section').find('div.section-wrapper').addClass('active')
    } else {
      $('section').find('menu').addClass('hidden')
      $('section').find('div.section-wrapper').removeClass('active')
    }
  })
```

Using a timeout will speed things up since it doesn't need to run everytime the browser size changes by 1 pixel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery

Comment: If you want to test out your performance JSPerf (http://jsperf.com/) is great for that. You can create isolated test cases with entire sections of code, or even compare one method with another.

Comment: you can still improve your code with variable caching and adding the timeout will improve performance.

Comment: In this case, variable caching wouldn't help. I need the updated page width. And ultimately, media queries are faster. If you have to use the document width in JS, use [document.body.clientWidth](http://jsperf.com/get-width)